# Possible Error in SQL Query DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

I'm trying to retrieve the number of rows that meet my condition but i keep getting 0 rows returned..

SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM AuditActivity 
WHERE Username = '______' 
  AND DateTimeActivity >= CONVERT(datetime, '01/08/2017 00:00:00') 
  AND DateTimeActivity <= CONVERT(datetime, '01/08/2017 23:59:59') 
  AND ActivityType = 'Login'
```

Data in SQL Server table:

[image: Data]

Codes used in Method to retrieve:

```
// Bar Chart Current Week Monday (Login)
public int barMondayLogin(String username)
{
    int result = 0;

    StringBuilder sqlCmd = new StringBuilder();
    sqlCmd.AppendLine("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AuditActivity WHERE Username = @getUsername AND DateTimeActivity BETWEEN @getFirstDT AND @getLastDT AND ActivityType = @getType");

    try
    {
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionStr);

        myConn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd.ToString(), myConn);

        //DateTime
        DateTime currentDT = DateTime.Today;

        DateTime FirstDT = currentDT.AddDays(-(int)currentDT.DayOfWeek + 1);
        DateTime SecondDT = FirstDT.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);

        Debug.WriteLine("Date: " + FirstDT + " " + SecondDT);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getUsername", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getFirstDT", FirstDT);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getLastDT", SecondDT);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getType", "Login");

        myConn.Close();

        return result;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        logManager log = new logManager();
        log.addLog("AuditNLoggingDAO.barMondayLogin", sqlCmd.ToString(), ex);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Could it be possible the datetime is formatted wrongly?

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: try a locale agnostic format: '20170801 23:59:59'

Comment: You shouldn't really use string in a where clause; you should use identifiers. Also, you don't need to format a datetime you retrieve from a database; try it without?

Comment: Can you please update which method you are using to retrieve data? ExecuteNonQuery or ExecuteScalar?

Comment: i don't see `cmd.ExecuteReader();`?

Comment: I don't think it is the cause of your issue, but I'd still recommend reading [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), and also [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Have you tried manually executing your sql from the command line?

Comment: If this is solved then mark a response as the answer.  **Do not** edit your title to say "[Solved]".

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that your date formats are different, Database may have other format and c# have some other format, firt try to get format of ms sql and then convert your date format according to that and then add it in condition. Also make sure if you really need to compare time in date.

Answer (score 0):

As [Selva TS noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466009/possible-error-in-sql-query-datetime#comment77893029_45466009), I forgot a line of code. Specifically, I missed ExecuteScalar. With that fixed, everything is working now.